# What is the smallest SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF sizes possible on Windows and Linux?

Tags: sockets, tcp, buffer

On Windows and Linux, what are the smallest possible SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF sizes possible?  Is it 1 byte?  Does setting these values to 1 achieve the smallest possible?  Does the OS delay allocating the RAM until the space is needed?

I realize that this will cause terrible performance for transferring data.  I am not trying to transfer data.  I am trying to check if a server is listening to a port and if not flag a problem.

Comment: *I am trying to check if a server is listening to a port and if not flag a problem.* - If that's what you are *really trying to do*, then the simplest approach would be to just connect to that port and close the connection upon success.  Why do you need to mess with the buf sizes?  How often does this check need to run? (Seems like a micro-optimization)

Comment: I have thousands of ports to check every hour.  I probably need to figure out how to send just a SYN packet and not the full TCP handshake.

Comment: You don't need to know. Just set it to 1. The system will enforce whatever its minimum is. What this has to do with port scanning is a mystery.

Comment: While port scanning, I would like to conserve system resources for other operations on a busy server.  Minimizing the memory usage by these port scanning sockets is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the minimum value of SO_RCVBUF is slightly more than 2048, and the minimum value of SO_SNDBUF is double the minimum value of SO_RCVBUF.

The Linux source [include/net/sock.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/net/sock.h#L2545) defines the minimum values as:

```
/* Since sk_{r,w}mem_alloc sums skb->truesize, even a small frame might
 * need sizeof(sk_buff) + MTU + padding, unless net driver perform copybreak.
 * Note: for send buffers, TCP works better if we can build two skbs at
 * minimum.
 */
#define TCP_SKB_MIN_TRUESIZE    (2048 + SKB_DATA_ALIGN(sizeof(struct sk_buff)))

#define SOCK_MIN_SNDBUF         (TCP_SKB_MIN_TRUESIZE * 2)
#define SOCK_MIN_RCVBUF          TCP_SKB_MIN_TRUESIZE
```

SOCK_MIN_SNDBUF is the minimum SO_SNDBUF and SOCK_MIN_RCVBUF is the minimum SO_RCVBUF.

The definition of SOCK_MIN_RCVBUF is `(2048 + SKB_DATA_ALIGN(sizeof(struct sk_buff)))` which is 2048 bytes plus the length of an L1-cache-aligned [packet struct](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/skbuff.html). The minimum value of SO_SNDBUF is double the minimum size of `SO_RCVBUF`.

The `__sock_set_rcvbuf` function in [net/core/sock.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/sock.c#L962) contains a comment that explains why the requested buffer size is doubled, and why the doubled size is returned when reading the size:

```
static void __sock_set_rcvbuf(struct sock *sk, int val)
{
        /* Ensure val * 2 fits into an int, to prevent max_t() from treating it
         * as a negative value.
         */
        val = min_t(int, val, INT_MAX / 2);
        sk->sk_userlocks |= SOCK_RCVBUF_LOCK;

        /* We double it on the way in to account for "struct sk_buff" etc.
         * overhead.   Applications assume that the SO_RCVBUF setting they make
         * will allow that much actual data to be received on that socket.
         *
         * Applications are unaware that "struct sk_buff" and other overheads
         * allocate from the receive buffer during socket buffer allocation.
         *
         * And after considering the possible alternatives, returning the value
         * we actually used in getsockopt is the most desirable behavior.
         */
        WRITE_ONCE(sk->sk_rcvbuf, max_t(int, val * 2, SOCK_MIN_RCVBUF));
}
```

---

The socket man page contains the following explanation but **the minimum values are not correct**:

$ man 7 socket

**SO_SNDBUF**

Sets or gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.  The
kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping
overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this
doubled value is returned by getsockopt(2).  The default
value is set by the /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default file
and the maximum allowed value is set by the /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max file.  **The minimum (doubled)
value for this option is 2048. (wrong)**

**SO_RCVBUF**

Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes. The  kernel doubles  this  value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled value is returned by get‐sockopt(2). The default value is set    by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default file, and the maximum allowed value is set  by  the  /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max file.  **The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256. (wrong)**

Comment: Worth noting that the actual minimum on _your_ OS might be different. `python3 -c "import socket as S; s=S.socket(); s.setsockopt(S.SOL_SOCKET, S.SO_RCVBUF, 1); print(s.getsockopt(S.SOL_SOCKET, S.SO_RCVBUF))"` on a modern Linux → **2304** (despite what `man 7 socket` on the same system says), on Windows 11 → **1**

Comment: @Yirkha Good catch. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just in the "thousands of ports per hour" as you mentioned in your comment, chances are high your server is already getting an order of magnitude more connections per hour than what your test runner would impose. Just do a "connect", then a "close".   Anything else is a micro-optimization.

And if there's any sort of proxy, port mapper, or load balancer involved, then testing the TCP connection itself may not be sufficient.  You would want to actually test the application protocol being hosted on that socket.  For example, if there is a web server running on port 8000, you should not only make a TCP connection, but actually make an HTTP request and see if you get any kind of response back.

Comment: Exactly. Thousands per hour is sixteens per minute, or ones per four seconds.

Comment: Hmm... the request to port scan a lot of servers comes as a spike.  So, I cannot spread the port scans out.  So, it turns out to be 1000+ all at once.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me the "spike" that you speak of isn't from the operating system or TCP stack, but rather from the actual application code that reacts to a new incoming connection being established.  Not sure why you can't spread the scan out...

Comment: The spike is from the actual application code.  The application has to check 1000s of ports quickly to finish its report.  A minute later, it will generate a different report against a different set of 1000+ machines.